# How to authenticate once for multiple requests to the same domain?

Tags: python, python-requests

I need get data from a server which is authenticated by LDAP. It's very time consuming if LDAP authentication is required for each request.
How can I authenticate once for all requests?
I try to use session in Python's Requests Library but it's not work.

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

class HttpRequests:

    def __init__(self, collector):
        self._session = requests.Session()
        self._collector = collector
        print("Init session to {}".format(collector._server))
        self._session.post(collector._server, auth=(self._collector._user, self._collector._passwd), verify=(not self._collector._insecure))


    def getHttpResponse(self, my_url): 
        # make a GET request
        # response = self._session.get(my_url, auth=(self._collector._user, self._collector._passwd), verify=(not self._collector._insecure)) \
        #     if self._collector._user and self._collector._passwd else self._session.get(my_url, verify=(not self._collector._insecure))

        response = self._session.get(my_url, verify=(not self._collector._insecure))

        #Connection fail
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print('******************************************************************************************')
            print('  Connection fail: ')
            print('   - Status code: {}'.format(response.status_code))
            print('   - Url: {}'.format(my_url))
            print('   - Username: {}'.format(self._collector._user))
            print('   - Password: {}'.format(self._collector._passwd))
            print('******************************************************************************************')

        return response
```

- Status code: 403